# Magento 2 Currency Setup - Allowed Currencies programmatically

Tags: magento2, currency, programmatically, setup

How to set 'Allowed Currencies' for each store programmatically in Magento2.

Options in Admin Panel are placed here:

```
System -> Configuration -> General -> Currency Setup
```

Also I'm not sure where exactly these informations are stored in magento database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to Select your store from top:
 [image]

Then set your allowed currency for your current store and hit on save.

You can see the selected values in database -> 'core_config_data'. It would be saved on the following path:
for allowed currencies: currency/options/allow

for base currency: currency/options/base

for default currency: currency/options/default

cheers !!